# Encode base64 in Freemarker template

Tags: java, base64, freemarker

Is there a way to convert a byte array to base64 in a Freemarker template?  Something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${photo.data?base64}" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: I built the whole string with escaped enclosing quotes and substituted the entire variable without the quotes in the template. <img src=${invoiceNumberBarcode} />  with invoiceNumberBarcode like this: "\"data:image/jpg;base64," + base64BarcodeJpg + "\"";  I'm wondering why people are dealing with the mess in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way in the current release. (But of course you can call your own method to do it.)

The object whose methods you want to call must be put into the data-model (i.e. the template context). (For statics: [freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_55](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_55))

But, for easier maintenance, I prefer this: create class `com.foo.Base64EncoderMethod implements TemplateMethodModelEx` (that calls `Base64.encodeBase64` internally), then create a template `lib/utils.ftl` (if you don't already have something like that) and in that, call `<#assign base64Encode = 'com.foo.Base64EncoderMethod'?new()>`.  Then in the templates, call `<#import '/lib/utils.ftl' as u>` and `${u.base64Encode(photo.data)}`

Comment: How do you do that?  I use commons-codec to do base64 encoding in my application.  The function is: `Base64.encodeBase64(byte[])`

Comment: The object whose methods you want to call must be put into the data-model (= template context). (For statics: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_55) But, for easier maintenance, I prefer this: create `class com.foo.Base64EncoderMethod implements TemplateMethodModelEx` (that calls `Base64.encodeBase64` internally), then create a template `lib/utils.ftl` (if you don't already have something like that), in that `<#assign base64Encode = 'com.foo.Base64EncoderMethod'?new()>`, then in the templates `<#import '/lib/utils.ftl' as u>` and `${base64Encode(photo.data)}`.

Comment: Creating a `TemplateMethodModelEx` implementation is a hassel.  It converts the byte array to a `SimpleSequence` object containing a `List` of `Byte` objects, which you have to iterate over in order to convert back to a primitive `byte` array for the base64 encoder.  I  think I prefer the static model technique in this situation.

Comment: That `byte[]` conversion things is horrible indeed. But I believe that's a problem specific to the `DefaultObjectWrapper`. I have always used a pure `BeansWrapper` instead (or, a custom extended one) as the global `object_wrapper` setting. Then I can get back the original object where it makes sense. But switching wrapper is not so easy in existing applications, as it may breaks existing templates. BTW, the static stuff uses `BeansWrapper` too.

Comment: Actually, what I ended up doing was creating a plain `Base64Generator` class that doesn't extend anything and that has a `encode(byte[])` method.  I just created an instance of this class and passed it into the data model.  Seems to work OK.

Comment: How efficiently that works depends on what wrapped the `byte[]`. What happens is that `DefaultObjectWrapper` doesn't recognize anything in the `Base64Generator` object that it can handle (and hence ruin...), so the wrapping of the object falls back to `BeansWrapper`. So far good. But if the `byte[]` argument was wrapped by `DefaultObjectWrapper`, then `BeansWrapper` will face the same situation as you did with `TemplateMethodModelEx` (that the original array is lost, and it has to recreate it from a `List<Byte>`).

Comment: Sounds like if I created my own `BeansWrapper` implementation I could prevent it from mucking with the byte array.

Comment: Simply using `BeansWrapper` instead of the `DefaultObjectWrapper` solves that. Of course you may still want to extend `BeansWrapper`. Oh, and something you probably want to do with `BeansWrapper` is setting its `simpleMapWrapper` property to `true`.